# Linkedin latest updates / activity in <iframe> to display on my website?

Tags: linkedin-api, feed, posts

I want display all Linkedin latest feeds on my website, it will helpful if it should in Embed(...) code

Answer (score 0):

You could refer to the [API for LinkedIn Activity](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/guide/v2/shares/activity-feed) and create an html element based on that.